# How to combine gulp-tasks-appfy with expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, server, gulp

Here is the gulp-appfy-tasks site.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-appfy-tasks
Does anyone know how to use appfy to build an express server? Thanks in advance